# Is it an action to voluntarily end a grapple?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, grapple

If a monster, such as a Chuul, has grappled a character can they end the grapple for free?

EG a Chuul attacks a halfling with a pincer attack and hits, the halfling is now considered grappled, trapped in its pincers. The Chuul then grappled another character with its other pincer and finally paralyses the halfling with the tentacle.

I know it can still attack with its pincers in subsequent turns but, if it wanted to now grapple a 3rd character could it voluntarily drop the halfling and would this be a “free” action? Alternativley if the halfling was not paralyzed could it also now end the grapple and still attack?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### No action is required to release a grapple.

The [rules for grappling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Grappling) state:

> [...] you can release the target whenever you like (no action required).

Comment: do you know what, I read and read the rules and seemed to just not see that sentence until you pointed it out. Hate it when the brain does that :) Thankyou

Comment: @RichardC Happens to the best of us. Happy to help.